# Backbone.js model's destroy method does not trigger success or error event

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, mustache, backbone-events, js-amd

I am beginning to learn Backbone.js and I started with [this boilerplate](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backboneboilerplate) and made an example by loading JSON data from a static file on disk and display it in an html table.

Then I tried to bind an event on a button which is supposed to delete an element from the collection, then from the DOM. The thing works fine, the click triggers the `destroy` method, the `remove` event is triggered on the collection, but nothing comes out of the `success` or `error` callbacks of `destroy`

Anybody have a clue ?

The model :

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var memberModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/members.json",
    defaults: {
      email: "",
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      gender: "",
      language: "",
      consent: false,
      guid: "",
      creationDate: ""
    },
    initialize: function(){
    }

  });

  return memberModel;

});
```

The view :

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'mustache',
  'collections/members',
  'text!templates/members/page.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, Mustache, membersCollection, membersPageTemplate){
  var membersPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    initialize: function(){
        this.members = new membersCollection();

        this.members.on('remove', function(){
                // works fine
            $('.members-body tr').first().remove();
            console.log('removed from collection');
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        var that = this;

        this.members.fetch({success: function(){

            var wrappedMembers = {"members" : that.members.toJSON()};

            that.$el.html(Mustache.render(membersPageTemplate, wrappedMembers));

            $('#delete-member').click(function(){
                that.members.at(0).destroy({ 
                        // prints nothing!!!
                    success: function(){ console.log('sucess'); }, 
                    error: function(){ console.log('error'); }
                });

            });

        }});

    }
  });
  return membersPage;
});
```

Comment: Do you have a `url` set for your models or collection?

Comment: Yes, `url` is set on both model and collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I agree that this is odd.  I'm not entirely sure what's happening yet, but here is what I suspect...*

Your `Destroy()` calls aren't returning valid JSON.

- Watching firebug,fiddler, or whatever, what do your destroy() responses look like?
- I'm also curious what `that` is when your delete-click function is triggered.
- Does destroy return false or a jqXHR object?

There is a bit a disconnect in backbone (at least i was for me at first).  When calling `destroy()` or fetch/save for that matter, the call is async.   Immediately after the call the delete event fires and your collection can respond.  But, digging a bit deeper in the documentation, another event is fired up confirmation of the delete:

> **and** a "sync" event, **after** the server has successfully acknowledged the model's deletion

So your collection is acting on the presumption that the delete has succeeded.  If you want your collection to respond to a confirmed delete, look for the `sync` event.

This leaves one nagging point -- why isn't your error handler firing?  Well, the callbacks are designed to respond to the confirmation of a delete. But I bet the JS call stack doesn't know how to interpret the response it's getting back, as a success or error. You likely stumbled across the realities of AJAX.  I've found in backbone, jquery, and  bunch of other frameworks that you can confuse the ajax error handling.  Google "jquery ajax error not called" and you'll find a host of different scenarios where the error event isn't triggered.

---

**UPDATE**

After the comments back and forth...two things are happening.  First, your model is perceived as 'new' which means calls to `Destroy()` don't make server requests. As a result your success/error don't fire.  See [this commit](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/232).

With that said, I don't think you consider your model new (not persisted to the server).  You need to do one of two things.  Either include a property named `id` **OR** in your model map  your  models ID (`guid` i assume) to the ID of the model.  Mapping is easy by appling the following line to your model: `idAttribute: "guid"`.  You can see more on the [idAttribute here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-idAttribute).

Comment: I am testing in Google Chrome, and when I look at the Network tab, it does nothing when I call `destroy`. I also tried Fiddler to check if a DELETE http request is sent, but there too, nothing's going on.

Comment: Please add your model definition to the original post (including the JSON response from fetch). Also, just before the delete what is the value of `that.members.at(0).IsNew`?

Comment: Also, this line `this.members = new membersCollection;` is odd.  I would either expect a direct assigment, or if you're using `new` parenthesis after `membersCollection()`

Comment: I added my model, `that.members.at(0).IsNew` is `undefined` just before the `destroy` call

I also added parenthesis after `new membersCollection`

Comment: sorry...typo on my part `isNew` (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-isNew). Also, what is the url on your Collection?

Comment: isNew() is true
URL on the collection : /members.json

Comment: @EBarr "what do your destroy() responses look like" what should the response look like? I am having the same problem where delete does call the server but no event fired. I return an empty response with status ok from the server

Comment: @UsmanIsmail - All you should need back is an HTTP 200.  Sounds like you're request might be error-ing, but it's tough to say without a code sample/setup.